# LINQ to XML to create complex XML File

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, linq

I would like to know if there is any simple/fast way to create a complex `XML` file, when I say complex, I mean more than 20 elements encapsulated. Although this is VB.net, unfortunately literals will not work in this case. Some advice will be most certainly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to [System.Xml.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx) tools from .Net 3.5.  Even if you aren't using Linq at all, and not using XML literals, it's still a **fantastic library** for dynamically building XML in code.  But since you say you *can't* use XML literals, does that mean you're in a .Net 3.0 or before project, and you can't upgrade?  That would be very unfortunate, to not be able to use the best tooling.

Assuming you can use [System.Xml.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx), and you just have a silly boss who is against the XML literals syntactic sugar (some sort of language snob perhaps?), then you need to get familiar with the library, centered around the XElement class.

I would **strongly suggest** watching the following video casts on dnrtv, [Part1](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=80) and [Part2](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=81).

Comment: I'm using .Net Framework 3.5, the problem with the literals is due to the fact that I need to do alot of manipulation with the XML and the expressions that come along with it are just not enough.

Comment: That makes sense.  I understand where you're coming from.  A *little* use of the xmlLiterals inline syntax ( `<% = variable %>`) is great.  To much though, and it gets crazy fast.  But using XElements etc. (which is what xml literals under the hood) is still great for building xml, once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 2):

[XLinq: Create XML from object using LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2007/02/20/xlinq-create-xml-from-object-using-linq.aspx)

To play with the XML data if you are using .net version 3.5 its better to user [**LINQ to XML**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24376/LINQ-to-XML

**or**

[Manipulate XML data with XPath and XmlDocument (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C)